# Visibility of a child Control not working inside parent

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` inside a `Grid` which is inside a `UserControl`. I have set the Visibility of the `StackPanel` based on a property called `ShowInstrumentAction` that is present in the `ViewModel`, which is set as a `DataContext`. This operation works just fine.

But I have a button inside this `StackPanel` (please see `PrimeFlush3TimesButton`) which I want it to be visible based on some other condition. But the child level visibility won't work.

Is it possible  to do this kind of binding?
Or should I write a style for Visibility on the button?
I'm not sure what may be the right approach. Please help.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="InstrumentOperationsPanel" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowInstrumentAction,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="PrimeButton"
            Content="{StaticResource InstrumentPrime}"
            Margin="{StaticResource AllControlsMargin}" Command="{Binding DataContext.InstrumentPrimeCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="FlushButton"
            Content="{StaticResource InstrumentFlush}"
            Margin="{StaticResource AllControlsMargin}" Command="{Binding DataContext.InstrumentFlushCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="PrimeFlush3TimesButton"
            Content="{StaticResource PrimeAndFlush3Times}"
            Margin="{StaticResource AllControlsMargin}"
            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsBuiltInUser,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=3},Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.InstrumentPrimeAndFlush3TimesCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ElementBinding`. Name the User Control.

```
    <Button x:Name="PrimeFlush3TimesButton"
        Content="{StaticResource PrimeAndFlush3Times}"
        Margin="{StaticResource AllControlsMargin}"
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName,Path=DataContext.IsBuiltInUser,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName,Path=DataContext.InstrumentPrimeAndFlush3TimesCommand}">
        </Button>
```

Comment: Sure let me try it out